# How to fix the exception "Message: timeout (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.50)" when i use selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

When I use selenium to automate, I find sometimes I will get the Exception:

```
Message: timeout   (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.90)
```

and I don't know what happened.

I tried to Google but I couldn't find the reason.

```py
try:
    li.click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="user-info"]/div[@class="user-info-detail"]/a').get_attribute('href')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

> "Message: timeout   (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.50)",
>   sometimes I will get the exception but in general it won't.

Comment: What's the task you're automating? Maybe it got stuck in a loop in certain cases? Or, maybe the connection to the site the for which you're automating the task times out after a while? It's hard to know without more context I think.

Comment: I want to know your browser settings. Try to add this: browser.maximize_window()

Comment: @Yun 
` 
    chrome_options=Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',['enable-automation'])
    chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3") 
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    browser.set_window_size(1920,1080)
` ``
these are my settings, and i find "browser.maximize_window()" don't work in headless mode, so I use the "set_window_size(1920,1080)".

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Message: timeout (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.50)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** instance *timed out* while attempting to locate the desired element rendered through **headless chrome=77.0**.

---

A bit of more information with respect to:

- *Selenium* client version
- *ChromeDriver* version
- Relevant [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way.

---

However, possibly the element exists but the *href* attribute was not rendered within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). As your usecase is to retrieve the *href* attribute of an WebElement, ideally you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()`. So your effective code block will be as follows:

```
try:
    print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='user-info']/div[@class='user-info-detail']/a"))).get_attribute("title"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Inducing *WebDriverWait* along with *ExpectedConditions* wouldn't through the raw message on the console.

Comment: this is a total guess